# How can I store the result of query into a variable?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my code:

```
BEGIN     
    IF (new.edited_id IS NULL) THEN
        IF (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE id = new.author_id AND IFNULL((active & b'1000000' > 0), 0) < 1) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "you cannot ask anymore";
        ELSEIF (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE id = new.author_id AND IFNULL((active & b'10000000' > 0), 0) < 1) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "you cannot answer anymore";
        END IF;
    ELSE 
        IF (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE id = new.author_id AND IFNULL((active & b'100000000' > 0), 0) < 1) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "you cannot edit anymore";
        END IF;
END
```

As you see, the conditions of those inner `IF` statements are almost the same. So how can I improve it? I mean how can I store the result of that query into a variable and then use that variable as conditions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can now use variable `condition` in if statements

```
SET @condition := (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE id = new.author_id AND IFNULL((active & b'1000000' > 0), 0) < 1);
```

Comment: There is three different numbers: `& b'1000000'`, `& b'10000000'` and `& b'100000000'`.

Comment: OK i didnt noticed that. In that case , all the queries have different results. So we cant use a single variable for all if conditions